# How to use optional command line arguments in a python function?

Tags: python, function, sys

I want a more compact and scalable way to use command line args to feed a python function, here is what i have:

```
def getRelevant (number = 5, sortBy = "Change"):
    number, sortBy = int(number), sortBy
    relevant = ...
    return relevant

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        print(getRelevant(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
        print(getRelevant(sys.argv[1]))
    else:
        print(getRelevant())
```

It works. But I'm not happy with this conditionals, is there a way to make it simpler?

Comment: You could work with *args to let your function accept more than one parameter. How ever you need to set default values in your function then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) should do this. It is feature rich and flexible. 
For your case, the below does the job:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your app here.')
parser.add_argument('-N', '--integers', default=5,  help='your help text here')
parser.add_argument('-S', '--sortby', default='Change', choices=['Change', 'SomeOtherOption'], help='some help text here ')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  args = parser.parse_args()
  print(args.integers) # prints 5 if nothing provided
  print(args.sortby)  # prints 'Change' if nothing provided
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with argparse or Typer

argparse: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

typer: https://typer.tiangolo.com/

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` is of course the tool you want to learn for commandline options and arguments - it's part of the tools alls devs should know about (with `logging` and `pdb`).

This being said, for this exact case, you could also solve the issue very simply without `argparse`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print(getRelevant(*args))
```